# How to make an image to fit the whole container width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my image to fit the whole container width.

[image]

I've tried :

- give my image of `width="100%"`
- place my image within a div that have width of `100%`

None of those work.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:gray;">
    <div width="100%">
        <img width="100%" src="http://s6.postimg.org/7ic0egypt/report_nav.png">
    </div>
</div
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/w9q0kabt/1/)

Comment: Check your margins and paddings.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. See my fiddle.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: OK I see now, I added my answer, its in your body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the container padding to `0`. I rewrote your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9q0kabt/3/) using CSS

Comment: Brian. I like your idea. changing the css to my container might effect others stuffs on my page. Is there any other way around it ?

Comment: You can add another class to it called something else. http://jsfiddle.net/w9q0kabt/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here add this to your css, by default the body has a margin of 8px.

```
body{margin: 0px;}
```